# Is there any one word to describe people who don't prefer the product?

Tags: single-word-requests

In terms of marketing, is there any simple word to describe non-preference in  a particular product?

Like Pick-up truck non-preferred type?

Comment: unpopular, less popular.

Answer (score 2):

Non-preferred or unpreferred are both correct but don't sound very elegant. Unfavored may suit your needs better.

Answer (score 1):

*People* who don't have a preference could be considered [**indifferent**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indifferent):

> [Merriam-Webster]
> **1** : marked by impartiality : UNBIASED
> **2 a** : that does not matter one way or the other
> **2 b** : of no importance or value one way or the other
> **3 a** : marked by no special liking for or dislike of something
> // *indifferent* about which task he was given
> **3 b** : marked by a lack of interest, enthusiasm, or concern for something : APATHETIC
> // *indifferent* to suffering and poverty

But, in terms of *marketing*, I'm sure that no company would like to think that somebody could never be swayed. So, from their perspective, people would never be *indifferent*, they would simply be [**undecided**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/undecided):

> **1** : not having made a decision
> // *undecided* voters

---

Note that this answers the title of your question. The body of your question seems to be asking something else—not for the name of *people* who don't prefer something, but for the name of a *thing* that nobody prefers.

The name for a such thing would be [**unwanted**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unwanted):

> : not wanted or needed
> // attracting *unwanted* attention
> // giving away some *unwanted* possessions

But, again in terms of *marketing*, companies might not want to think that *any* of their products are *unwanted*. They may simply choose to look at such products as [**nonprofitable**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nonprofitable):

> : not profitable
>
> *profitable*
> : affording profits : yielding advantageous returns or results

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a word describing the unloved product itself, or (as the title of your question suggests) the person who holds a dislike for the product?

I would suggest such a person be referred to as "a disliker".